Camera LensFacing verification failed, existing cameras: [Camera@6e9a9d0[id=0]] in CameraX plugin
I was developing an app in Kotlin which use the CameraX plugin to access to camera, and take a picture. After read a lot of related question with the error I'm reciving:
 Camera LensFacing verification failed, existing cameras: [Camera@ee95973[id=0]]
2024-04-08 08:26:29.899  6094-6343  CameraX W  Retry init. Start time 2293883 current time 2296127 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No available camera can be found at androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector.select(CameraSelector.java:94) at androidx.camera.core.impl.CameraValidator.validateCameras(CameraValidator.java:91) at androidx.camera.core.CameraX.lambda$initAndRetryRecursively$2$androidx-camera-core-CameraX(CameraX.java:334) at androidx.camera.core.CameraX$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.run(Unknown Source:10) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
2024-04-08 08:26:30.402  6094-6343  Camera-JNI I scan_packages:
2024-04-08 08:26:30.406  6094-6343  chatty  I  uid=10095 CameraX-core_ca identical 8 lines
2024-04-08 08:26:30.407  6094-6343  Camera-JNI  I  scan_packages:
2024-04-08 08:26:30.413  6094-6343  Camera2CameraInfo I  Device Level:INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED
2024-04-08 08:26:30.414  6094-6343  Camera-JNI I scan_packages: 2024-04-08 08:26:30.415  6094-6343  chatty I  uid=10095 CameraX-core_ca identical 2 lines 2024-04-08 08:26:30.416  6094-6343  Camera-JNI I  scan_packages:2024-04-08 08:26:30.419  6094-6343  CameraValidator E  Camera LensFacing verification failed, existing cameras: [Camera@36483eb[id=0] 2024-04-08 08:26:30.419  6094-6343  CameraX E  The device might underreport the amount of the cameras. Finish the initialize task since we are already reaching the maximum number of retries.

So, the common soluions for this issues, usually are permission issue, but I check again and again my manifest, and i'd say it fine:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        android:required="true"
        android:requiredFeature="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

It's really wear due to I can manually give the camera permission to the app from the settings device which is a PAX A920.
The error rise when this line of the following activity is called:
PermissionChecker.checkCamera(
            logger,
            this,
            uiAlert(R.string.permission_request_title, R.string.permission_request_message)
        )

And here the method to check the permission:
PermissionChecker.kt
 fun checkCamera(logger: ILog, activity: Activity, uiAlert: UIAlert): Boolean {
        var result = check(logger, activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA, uiAlert)
        result = check(
            logger,
            activity,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
            uiAlert
        ) && result
        logger.info("Camera permisson ${if(result) "GRANTED !!" else "DENIED !!" }")
        return result
    }

fun check(
        logger: ILog,
        activity: Activity,
        permission: String,
        requestAlert: UIAlert
    ): Boolean {
        return when {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                activity,
                permission
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
                logger.debug("Permission $permission is granted!!")
                true
            }

            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission) -> {
                // TODO: Invertir, agregar un método "confirm" en UIAlert
                activity.alertConfirm(
                    requestAlert,
                    onYes = { requestPermission(logger, permission, activity) }
                )
                false
            }

            else -> {
                requestPermission(logger, permission, activity)
                false
            }
        }
    }

    private fun requestPermission(
        logger: ILog,
        permission: String,
        activity: Activity
    ) {
        logger.info("Asking permission: $permission")
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            activity,
            arrayOf(permission),
            REQUEST_CODE
        )
    }



So after try to manually give the camera permission which appears to not be allowed in A920 device, and check the permission in the app, What else can I do?
